# Highcharts: How do I set dynamic data to the drilldown pie chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am able to set data to the main pie chart using

```
var data = [1,2,3,4,5]; //value of data will be returned through an AJAX call
chart1.series[0].setData(data);
```

Similarly, how do I set the drilldown data dynamically?

I tried with

```
chart1.drilldown[0].data = '[1,2,3]';
```

but it did not work.

I am using `RESTful` services to expose data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can access drilldown at runtime using *chart.options.drilldown*

```
var newDrillDowns = {
                id: 'my drilldowns',
                data: [
                    ['Cat1', 4],
                    ['Cat2', 2],
                    ['Cat3', 1]
                ]};

chart.options.drilldown.series[0] = newDrillDowns;
```

In the same way you can replace drilldowns completely

```
chart.options.drilldown.series = [newDrillDowns];
```

Comment: Thanks. I am able to set the data manually now.
But, now I am stuck with another problem. My REST API is returning 
`[{id : 'INITIAL',data :[['Type 1',4], ['Type 2',3], ['Type 5',5]]}, {id : 'JOINED',data :[['Type 5',1]]}]`.

But the `chart.options.drilldown.series = [newDrillDowns]` is setting this data as a `String`. How do I rectify this ?

Comment: You just need to do the same: var response = [{id : 'INITIAL',data :[['Type 1',4], ['Type 2',3], ['Type 5',5]]}, {id : 'JOINED',data :[['Type 5',1]]}];
chart.options.drilldown.series = response;
It should work provided your data series have references to 'INITIAL' and 'JOINED' drilldowns

Comment: Thank you, it works! Had some errors in the JSON output. Rectified them and now it perfectly works .

Comment: Thanks, you saved my life!